# JQuery: How to get an element to show up once the user clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JQuery. The assignment I have to do is a card game where two players play to beat each other's sum. Anyways I am having trouble with the initial step of getting the game area to show up once the user enters their names and clicks "new game". I was able to successfully hide the game when the page loads, but at the moment when I enter the names and click new game, nothing happens. I prevented defaults and I do have the .show in there in the method as well. Does anyone know how to do this? This is my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".GameArea").hide();
  GameStart(); 
 });

 function GameStart(){
 $(".PlayerID").on("button",function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();

    setupUsers();
    turnSetUp();
     });
      }

    function setupUsers(){
    Player1Name = document.PlayerName;
    Player2Name = document.PlayerName2;

     var player1Score = 0;
     var player2Score = 0;

     var x = [[Player1Name,Player1Score], [Player2Name, Player2Score]];

     $(".GameArea").show(); 

     }

    function turnSetUp(){
    $.post("link.php") //this is a full php address that was provided to me, ignore the link
    .done(function (data){ 
       var deck = $.parseJSON(data);
       resetListeners();
          //deck.Cards[0] is the value to beat 
          //loop to get the remainder cards from the deck  
         });
          }         

        function resetListeners(){
        $(".GameArea a").on("click", function(fixCard){
        //event.preventDefault();
        //console.log( $( this ).text() );
        });
         }


       function fixCard(){

           }


      function calculateCurrentScore(){

      }


      function EndGame(){

        }
```

This is the Game Area of the html too

```
           <div class="GameArea">

            <span id="firstgroup">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="Desktop Cards/desktopCard0.png" alt="0"/>
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="Desktop Cards/desktopCard1.png" alt="1"/>
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="Desktop Cards/desktopCard2.png" alt="2"/>
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="Desktop Cards/desktopCard3.png" alt="3"/>
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="Desktop Cards/desktopCard4.png" alt="4"/>
                </a>
            </span>

            <span id="secondgroup"> 
                <a href="">
                    <img src="Desktop Cards/desktopCard0.png" alt="0"/>
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="Desktop Cards/desktopCard1.png" alt="1"/>
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="Desktop Cards/desktopCard2.png" alt="2"/>
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="Desktop Cards/desktopCard3.png" alt="3"/>
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="Desktop Cards/desktopCard4.png" alt="4"/>
                </a>

            </span>
        </div>
```

Comment: Maybe there is error before line *$(".GameArea").show();*, you should open Developer Tool of your browser (press F12 on Chome or IE) and check at Console tab.

Comment: Yeah I already checked that and there is no error.

Comment: After function *GameStart* is called, have you checked the size and properties of *GameArea*? You should make sure its *width, height* are larger than 0 and style is "display: block"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be having an error here in your code.

```
 function GameStart(){
   $(".PlayerID").on("button",function(event) { 
   event.preventDefault();

   setupUsers();
   turnSetUp();
   });
  }
```

when using the jquery on function you are saying on "button" which really doesn't mean anything, what we need to do is select the button in the $([button id]) and create an on click event. Kind of like this.

```
$("[id for area to show]").on("click",function(event) {
  //code to display game area goes here.
}
```

In the future I would isolating the issue, or even checking out the developer console on google chrome. The error messages can be easily tracked here, and can let you know what is going wrong.

Comment: The problem is when I put "click" instead, it actually shows the game area as soon as you click the type bar, rather than showing it when you click "New Game". Do you think I need to make a separate ID for the button?

Comment: Whoa dude thanks! This is actually my real first answer on this site :)